# Creating a php file using php File Write

Tags: php

I tried to create a php file  and save it in a root directory but it give error while doing it

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE),
>   expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number
>   (T_NUM_STRING) in C:\xampp\htdocs\page\cjl\configAlter.php on line 181

here is my code

```
<?php
$IndexFile = 'default.php';
$IndexCont = "<?php
session_start();
$currentBas = basename(dirname(__FILE__));
$parentBas = basename(dirname(dirname($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'])));//Line 181
$DIR = __DIR__;
require('../../srcc/default.php');
?>";
//This is already define $parentDir."".$SubFolderjailorgname
$fileDirectoryR = $parentDir."".$SubFolderjailorgname;
$myReadfile = fopen($fileDirectoryR.'/'.$IndexFile, "w") or die("Failed to open file!");
fwrite($myReadfile, $IndexCont);
fclose($myReadfile);
//END CREATE TEXT TO FILE
?>
```

Comment: Replace double quotes with single quotes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using double quotes `"` means your $_SERVER becomes evaluated in the `$IndexCont` string.

If you didn't mean it to be evaluated, use single quotes.

If you did need it evaluated, the resulting value in the string would be a syntax error when that new file is loaded, try adding single quotes around it.

Comment: You'll need to escape any single quotes within the string with \